# Random dice tipping

Tags: code-golf, random, repeated-transformation

In a standard dice (die) the numbers are arranged so that opposite faces add to seven.
Write the shortest possible program in your preferred language which outputs a random throw followed by 9 random tippings. A tipping is a quarter turn of the dice, e.g. if the dice is facing 5, all possible tippings are 1,3,4 and 6.

Example of desired output:

> 1532131356

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### GolfScript, 26 chars

```
0{(.6,5@--\-.,rand=).}10*;
```

A slight more compressed version of [Joey](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/15/joey)'s, basically working around the issue with zero-indexing.

Answer (score 9):

### Ruby, 44

```
c=0;10.times{$><<c=([*1..6]-[c,7-c]).sample}
```

I found the [*1..6] trick by lucky experimenting.

Comment: Some nice tricks here, great stuff. Hitting myself on the head for missing the Array#sample method.

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (71 characters)

You may need to replace `print` with `alert` or something else, depending on your JavaScript environment.

```
for(C=L=T=0;C++<10;print(L=T))while(!(T-L&&T+L-7))T=Math.random()*6+1|0
```

Comment: merge loops by conditionally incrementing the outer one when a value is found : for(b=n=10;n;a-b&&a+b-7&&print(b=a,n--))a=Math.random()*6+1|0

Answer (score 4):

### GolfScript, 28

```
0:|;{7,[0|7|-]-.,rand=:|}10*
```

Answer (score 3):

**Bash**

```
#/!bin/bash
f=`expr $RANDOM % 6` 
f=`expr $f + 1`
printf "$f"
for ((i=0; i<9; i++))
do
   ((bad=7-$f))
   next=`expr $RANDOM % 6`
   next=`expr $next + 1`
   while [ $next -eq $bad ] || [ $next -eq $f ]
   do
      next=`expr $RANDOM % 6`
      next=`expr $next + 1`
   done
printf "$next"
f=$next
done
```

sample code: http://ideone.com/CCfro

Comment: The use of `((var=expression))` is very nice - I thought that the shortest way was `var=$((expression))` But why do you use that once only and waste tonnes of characters on expr in backticks?

Comment: I dont do much of shell scripting, but for some reason ((var=expr)) in some places got failed (yeah weird :P )  Since I started this script, I just somehow completed. :)

Answer (score 3):

#### Bash: <strike>97 94 92 90 89</strike> 87

Heavily golfed from Aman ZeeK Verma's answer:

```
for((i=10,f=0;i--;))do
for((n=f;n==f||n+f==7;f=RANDOM%6+1))do :
done
printf $f
done
```

http://ideone.com/QiuTx

NB arguably it can be shrunk by 5 chars by changing the first line to `for((;i++<10;))` but that makes assumptions which aren't always valid. It would work ok in ideone but someone running it from a shell could have `i` or `f` exported to something non-zero.

Comment: I'd like to do a version without the inner loop, but I fear it will be longer.

Comment: This is extremely awesome, I am too raw for bash I guess :)

Comment: @Aman, most of it isn't bash-specific. It's just several dozen refinements with tests after each one and reversions when I broke something. The only bit which is really a bash trick is the noop, which I had to look up.

If you have time to read `man bash`, though, I recommend it. I once read it cover to cover, and just having a vague idea of what's possible and worth looking up has served me well.

Answer (score 3):

### R, <strike>56</strike> 52

```
for(i in 0:9)cat(F<-sample(setdiff(1:6,c(F,7-F)),1))
```

Comment: [Hi Sven, you can save 4 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/Py2/SCNTITNPwcDKUjM5sUTDzUa3ODG3ICdVozi1JCUzLU3D0MpMJ1nDTcdc101TU8dQU/P/fwA)

Comment: @JayCe Great idea, thank for pointing out!

Comment: My pleasure - and actually [you can save 5 more bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/Py2/SCNTITNPwcDKUjM5sUTDzUa3ODG3ICdVQ8PQykwzWjdZw03HXNdNM1bHUFPz/38A)

Answer (score 2):

### J, 30 characters

```
>:(?@4:{(i.6)-.],5&-)^:(<10)?6
```

`6 2 3 5 4 2 4 1 3 6`

Explanations (read from right to left):

- `?6` returns a random number between 0 and 5
- `^:(<10)` applies a function 9 times, accumulating the results along the way.  The function is:
- `?@4:{(i.6)-.],5&-`

  - `] , 5&-` returns an array of the input number and its complement to 5 (we're handling 0-based numbers currently, so the sum of opposite faces is 5)
  - `(i. 6) -.` removes them from the full set of integers 0 to 5.  We're left with all valid positions after a single tipping operation from the input position.
  - `?@4: {` picks one of those at random.
- `>:` increments the whole sequence to bring the figures back to the 1 to 6 interval.

Comment: Nice thought to ">:" at then end.

Comment: @Eelvex I have no idea why real-world dice are 1 to 6 when all sensible reasoning about them uses 0 to 5. :D

Answer (score 2):

### J

This should work but unfortunately J's random generator gets stuck after the 3rd iteration:

```
a=:>:i.6
f=:a#~1-(+&(a=])7&-)
((,(?4)&{@f@(_1&{))^:9)>:?6
```

`6 4 5 4 5 4 5 4 5 4`

Comment: I'm by no measure a J expert, but it seems to me from what I suffered composing my J answer to this thread that `(?4)` tends to be rolled once and treated as a constant for subsequent iterations if you're not careful around it.  I worked around it using a `(?@4:)`-like construct.

Answer (score 2):

#### Bash with only one loop: <strike>100 99 98</strike> 96

```
for((i=10,f=RANDOM%6+1;i--;))do
printf $f
((n=RANDOM%4+1,m=f<4?f:7-f,f=n<m||++n<7-m?n:n+1))
done
```

http://ideone.com/XrZO7

The key idea is that to pick a random number in [1,x] which isn't equal to y you can pick a random number in [1,x-1] and then increment if it's >= y. For this problem we want a random number in [1,6] which isn't equal to f or 7-f. We have to do the two tests in order min(f,7-f), max(f,7-f).

Assuming an initially empty environment could save 2 chars by not initialising i and changing the loop condition to `i++<10`

Answer (score 2):

### Windows PowerShell, 45

```
-join(0..9|%{($d=1..6-ne(7-$d)-ne$d|random)})
```

Pretty trivial, actually. I generate a list of possible dice rolls `1..6` and then select only those not equal to seven minus the last roll and then only those not equal to the last roll. From the remaining list I then select a random item and assign it to `$d`. Since `$d` is initially treated as `0` it rolls a normal die the first time.

Test script:

```
for($i=0;$i-lt20;$i++){
    $o=@(./tipping.ps1)
    if ($i-gt0-and$o-eq$o2) { throw "Must have random output" }
    if ($o.count-ne1) { throw "Must only have one line of output" }
    if ($o[0]-match'[^1-6]'){ throw "Invalid characters" }
    if($o[0].length-ne10){ throw "Wrong length: $($o[0].length)" }
    $r=[char[]]($o[0])|%{$_-48}
    for ($x=1;$x-lt$r.count;$x++){
        if ($r[$x-1]+$r[$x]-eq7) { throw "Not a tipping: $($r[$x-1]) and $($r[$x])" }
    }
    $o2=$o
}
```

History:

- 2011-02-18 11:57 (61) First attempt.
- 2011-02-18 11:58 (45) I don't need to generate the first number separately.

Comment: I get `The term 'random' is not recognized as a cmdlet, function, operable program, or script file. Verify the term and try again.`

Comment: @Peter: PowerShell v2, please. The `Get-Random` cmdlet didn't exist in v1.

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby

#### 66 characters

```
(0..9).reduce([]){|m|m<<((1..6).to_a-[d=m[-1]||0,7-d]).shuffle[0]}
```

Answer (score 2):

## TI-BASIC, <s>38</s> 34

```
For(I,1,9
Ans→X
Repeat Ans≠X and Ans≠7-X
randInt(1,6
End
Disp Ans
End
```

Boring solution, but it's shorter than the previous revision. I take advantage of the fact that on a fresh calculator, `Ans` is initialized to zero.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible, but I'll give 50 rep to anyone who can find a shorter solution.

Comment: How are you calculating 34?

Comment: Each token here is [one byte in memory](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/one-byte-tokens); it's standard for TI-BASIC to be scored this way. If you have a calculator, type the program in, look at the memory management screen, then subtract 9 and subract the length of the program's name to get the code size.

Answer (score 2):

### GS2, 16 bytes

```
16 2f 25 08 41 20 17 30 16 2f 31 31 25 09 19 32
```

Here's how it works

```
16 2f 25     # make range from 1 to 6 and push random element
08           # start block
    41       # duplicate top of stack twice
    20 17 30 # negate top of stack and add 7
    16 2f    # push range from 1 to 6
    31 31    # do set-wise difference with each of the two previous numbers
    25       # push a random element from the list
09           # end block
19 32        # repeat block 9 times
```

Comment: I think gs2 is newer than this challenge.

Answer (score 1):

### QBasic (71 characters)

The two newlines are necessary and included in the character count as one character each.

```
RANDOMIZE:FOR I=0TO 9
1N=INT(RND*6)+1:IF L=N OR L+N=7THEN 1
?N:L=N:NEXT
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 130 bytes

```java
v->{int d=(int)(Math.random()*6+1),i=10,p;String r=""+d;for(;i-->0;r+=d)for(p=d;p==d|p+d==7;d=(int)(Math.random()*6+1));return r;}
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##dZA/b8MgEMX3fIpTJqhj54@UdqBk65gslbpUHSiQhBQDgsNqlfqzuzjOWgl0upPu3e@9i@hE7YN2F/U1SCtSgr0w7joDMA51PAqp4TC2AK8YjTuBJG/eKOgoK9O@/PISCjQSDuCAw9DVu2vZBsVJKZTsBZ6bKJzyLaEPj9WaLgxfrxaB3SUjn88rxY4@EmbqerdiseKKjn3gigXO1W@oFOdP7H9NyqLGHB1E1g9s4gr50xauO143crfFHpnuvn@AoJO35RJevrXMqAHPGo7ZSTTewWYLaFqdAD2cNELyrYYk2mA1RJ2yxXTbH1FHy8UXA/PMN9tSququXrL7SajbxmdsQjmN1hHXSOKytfQW5BRlP@uHPw)

As full program with verbose main-method this would be **178 bytes** instead:

```java
interface M{static void main(String[]a){int d=(int)(Math.random()*6+1),i=10,p;String r=""+d;for(;i-->0;r+=d)for(p=d;p==d|p+d==7;d=(int)(Math.random()*6+1));System.out.print(r);}}
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##dYyxDoIwFEV/pWFqLRBYdGief8DEaBxeeKDF0DblSWKQb68YZ6eTm5x7Rlyw8KF3Iz1Sso77OGDXi2adGdl2YvGWxITWyZajdbfLFdW6e4JA7lCyQb6XER35SarDUdcqt1BXeTC/g4iQZZrM4KM0tijOlYkaSH13ADIBgN5BE8DJ/G8q075m7qfSP7kMe5dlVGbbUvoA)

Semi-port of [*@AmanZeeKVerma*'s Bash answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/963/52210).

**Explanation:**

```java
 v->{              // Method with empty unused parameter and String return-type
   int d=(int)(Math.random()*6+1),
                   //  Random dice-roll 1-6
       i=10,       //  Counter-integer, starting at 10
       p;          //  Temp integer to store new side
   String r=""+d;  //  Result-String, starting at the first dice-roll
   for(;i-->0;     //  Loop (1) 10 times:
       r+=d)       //    After every iteration, append the result with a random side
     for(p=d;      //   Set the new side to the current side
         p==d      //   Loop (2) as long as the new side and current side are the same
         |p+d==7;  //   or as long as both combined are exactly 7:
       d=(int)(Math.random()*6+1)
                   //    Set the new side to a random side 1-6
     );            //   End of loop (2)
                   //  End of loop (1) (implicit / single-line body)
  return r;        //  Return the result-String
}                  // End of method
```

Answer (score 1):

### MATLAB 58 bytes

```
a=randi(6)
for i=1:9;b=1:6;b([a,7-a])=[];a=b(randi(4))
end
```

Answer (score 0):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 71 bytes

I'm glad I could showcase ><>'s `x` code-pointer randomization as I don't recall seeing it here.

```
a&0 v
 /2v
1x3v 
>x< <<
6x4v
 \5v ~
:{:/ ^?=}
:{:/ ^?=7+}
:~$<^&;!?:-1&n
```

You can try it on [this online interpreter](http://fishlanguage.com/playground) (paste code, submit, start).

Comment: You'll get my upvote once you fix the solution.

Comment: @ThomasKwa Done, I might be able to golf it down a little bit but at least it's now functional.

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 67 bytes

```r
c(3,5,1,4,2,6)[(sample(1:6,1)+cumsum(sample((-2:2)[-3],9,T)))%%6+1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P1nDWMdUx1DHRMdIx0wzWqM4MbcgJ1XD0MpMx1BTO7k0t7g0FyaooWtkZaQZrWscq2OpE6KpqamqaqZtGPv/PwA)

There is [a golfier R answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/15991/80010) but this I think is a different approach from the answers submitted so far.

```r
c(3,5,1,4,2,6)                                                     #A dice and its facets
               (sample(1:6,1)                                      #Initial dice roll
                             +cumsum(sample((-2:2)[-3],9,T)))      #9 tippings in c(-2,-1,1,2)
                                                             %%6+1 #converts to values in [0,6]
              [                                                   ]#
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 23 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
6LΩUTFX?6LʒDXÊsX+7Ê*}ΩU
```

Can definitely be golfed, but I'm currently not seeing it..

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fzOfcytAQtwh7M59Tk1wiDncVR2ibH@7SqgUK//8PAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
6LΩ              # Pick a random value from the range [1,6]
                 #  i.e. [1,2,3,4,5,6] → 3
   U             # Save this random value in variable `X`
TF               # Loop 10 times:
  X?             #  Print `X` without newline to STDOUT
  6Lʒ     }      #  Create a range [1,6] again, and filter it by:
     DXÊ         #   Check if the current value is not equal to `X`
                 #    i.e. 1 and 3 → 1 (truthy)
                 #    i.e. 3 and 3 → 0 (falsey)
     sX+         #   Sum the current value with `X`
                 #    i.e. 1 and 3 → 4
                 #    i.e. 3 and 3 → 6
        7Ê       #   And check if it's not equal to 7
                 #    i.e. 4 and 7 → 1 (truthy)
                 #    i.e. 6 and 7 → 1 (truthy)
     *           #   If both checks are truthy, keep it in the filtered list
                 #    i.e. 1 and 1 → 1 (truthy)
                 #    i.e. 0 and 1 → 0 (falsey)
           Ω     #  Pick a random value from the filtered list
                 #   i.e. [1,2,5,6] → 1
            U    #  And save it in variable `X` for the next iteration of the loop
```