# Validate Random Die Tippers

Tags: code-golf, sequence, decision-problem

Almost six years ago, fellow PPCG member steenslag [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/958/13486) the following challenge:

> In a standard dice (die) the numbers are arranged so that opposite
>   faces add to seven. Write the shortest possible program in your
>   preferred language which outputs a random throw followed by 9 random
>   tippings. A tipping is a quarter turn of the dice, e.g. if the dice is
>   facing 5, all possible tippings are 1,3,4 and 6.
>
> Example of desired output:
>
> > 1532131356

So, now that everybody has completely forgotten about it and the winning answer has long since been accepted, we'll be writing a program to validate the die tipping sequences generated by the submitted solutions. (This makes sense. Just pretend it does.)

## Challenge

Your [program or function](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2422/13486)  is given a sequence such as `1532131356`. Validate that each consecutive digit is:

- Not equal to the previous digit
- Not equal to *7* minus *the previous digit*

(You don't have to validate the first digit.)

### Rules

- Your program must return a [truthy value if the input is valid and a falsey value](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2194/13486) otherwise.
- You can assume that the input consists of only the digits 1-6 and is at least 1 character long. Sequences won't have a fixed length like in steenslag's challenge.
- You can take the input as a string (`"324324"`), an array or array-like datastructure (`[1,3,5]`) or as multiple arguments (`yourFunction(1,2,4)`).

<sub>Standard [I/O](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/13486) and [loophole](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/13486) rules apply.</sub>

## Test cases

### Truthy

```
1353531414
3132124215
4142124136
46
4264626313135414154
6
2642156451212623232354621262412315654626212421451351563264123656353126413154124151545145146535351323
5414142
```

### Falsey

- Repeated digit

  ```
  11
  3132124225
  6423126354214136312144245354241324231415135454535141512135141323542451231236354513265426114231536245
  553141454631
  14265411
  ```
- Opposing side of die

  ```
  16
  42123523545426464236231321
  61362462636351
  62362462636361
  ```

Answer (score 13):

## Python 2, <strike>43</strike> 45 bytes

```
lambda s:reduce(lambda p,n:n*(7-p!=n!=p>0),s)
```

## 43 bytes (inspired heavily by @Zgarb)

```
lambda s:reduce(lambda p,n:n*(p>0<n^p<7),s)
```

This function combines my reduce statement with the bit-flicking logic from @Zgarb's answer, for a combination that is shorter than both.

Both answers output the following:

- 0 if the input is not a valid sequence
- The last digit of the sequence if it is valid

Comment: Welcome to PPCG,  This is a really nice first answer.

Comment: This doesn't work for about half of the false cases.  E.g. `3132124225` returns `5`.

Comment: You can fix it using `n and p*(7-p!=n!=p)`.

Comment: @JakeCobb It should work with all the test cases now. Unfortunately it's now 2 bytes longer :(

Comment: What a clever use of reduce, passing each value to the next step.

Answer (score 9):

### Python, 44 bytes

```py
lambda x:all(0<a^b<7for a,b in zip(x,x[1:]))
```

Bitwise magic!
This is an anonymous function that takes a list of integers, and checks that the XOR of every two consecutive elements is between 1 and 6 inclusive.

### Why it works

First, the XOR is always between 0 and 7 inclusive, since 7 is `111` in base 2, and our numbers have at most 3 binary digits.
For the equality, `a^b == 0` if and only if `a == b`.
Also, we have `7-a == 7^a` when `0 ≤ a ≤ 7`, and thus `a^b == 7` if and only if `a == 7^b == 7-b`.

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>11</s> 9 bytes

***-2 bytes for Osable's smart idea of using a product.***

```
¥¹D7-Á+«P
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@39o6aGdLua6hxu1D60O@P8/2lDHOBYA)

```
¥           # Push deltas.
 ¹D7-Á      # Push original array, and 7 - [Array] shifted right once.
      +     # Add original to the 7 - [Array] shifted right.
       «    # Concat both.
        P   # Product, if either contain a zero, results in 0, meaning false.
```

Third approach using 05AB1E, that doesn't use the pairwise command:

- `0` if it violates the tipsy properties.
- `Not 0` if there was nothing preventing it from being tipsy.

Comment: @Emigna didn't think it mattered but fixed!

Comment: I wanted to post an answer with deltas, but I did not think about `Á`. Nice!

Comment: You can save 2 bytes using the definition of truthy/falsy values with `¥¹D7-Á+«P` . It yields 0 when there is a 0 in the array or any other value otherwise.

Comment: @Osable SMAART! Mega smart man, good job.

Answer (score 6):

## R, <s>39</s> <s>37</s> <s>32</s> 31 bytes

```
all(q<-diff(x<-scan()),2*x+q-7)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzEnR6PQRjclMy1No8JGtzg5MU9DU1PHSKtCu1DXXPO/iYKRgpmCCRCDaGMFQyg2BYoZgjGQ9R8A)

Takes input from stdin. Uses `diff` to see if any two consecutive digits are the same; then compares each digit to 7 minus the previous digit. Returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Saved 5 bytes thanks to Jarko Dubbeldam, and another thanks to JayCe.

Comment: Saving the differences in some variable `q` and then testing `2*x+q-7` instead of `c(0,x)!=c(7-x,0)` saves a few bytes. If `x1 + x2 = 7` then `2*x1 + diff(x1,x2) = 7`. Checking `2*x+q - 7` then explicitly tests `!=0`.

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam Great observation, thanks! I've updated the solution.

Comment: [save 1 byte](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzEnR6PQRjclMy1No8JGtzg5MU9DU1PHSKtCu1DXXPO/iYKRgpmCCRCDaGMFQyg2BYoZgjGQ9R8A)

Comment: @JayCe Thanks, I've updated the answer now.

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 10 bytes

```
$ü+7Ê¹üÊ*P
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@69yeI@2@eGuQzsP7zncpRXw/7@xobGRoZGJkaEpAA)

Comment: Argh!, why didn't I think of `Ê` :P Nice!

Comment: Hmm, so `1*[] = []` but `product(1, []) = 1`. That's good to know.

Comment: @Emigna Actually, that is a bug. The product of `[]` should be 1.

Comment: Yeah, I've wished that it worked like that several times before. Order of operations also matter here. `)1*`, `)1s*` and `)1P` are all `[]` while `)1sP` is 1.

Comment: @Emigna Ahh, that's because the product of `[]` gives an error and is discarded. That's why it gives 1. I'll try to fix it when I get home.

Answer (score 5):

### R, <strike>49</strike> 44 bytes

```
!any(rle(x<-scan())$l-1,ts(x)==7-lag(ts(x)))
```

Reads input from stdin (separated by space) and outputs `TRUE/FALSE`. Will give a warning if input is of length one but still works.

Edit: saved a couple of bytes thanks to @rturnbull

Comment: You can combine `all(x)&all(y)` into `all(x,y)` to save some bytes. You can also switch `rle(x)$l==1` to `rle(x)$l-1`, which will then return a set of all `FALSE` if `x` is valid; then switch the later `!=` to an `==` and the `all` to `!any`. This yields `!any(rle(x<-scan())$l-1,ts(x)==7-lag(ts(x)))`, saving 5 bytes in total. (PS, I've written an [alternative solution](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/104083/59052) you may be interested in.)

Answer (score 4):

### Ruby, 34 bytes

```
->s{!s[/[16]{2}|[25]{2}|[34]{2}/]}
```

Comment: you could shave off two bytes by using the string `#[]` method instead:
`->s{!s[/[16]{2}|[25]{2}|[34]{2}/]}`

Comment: I didn't know you can use it with regex, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 15 bytes

```
ü+7å¹ü-0å¹g_~~_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@394j7b54aWHdh7eo2sAotPj6@ri//83NjQ2MjQyMTIyBQA) or as a [Test suite](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#RZBNTkNBDIP3uQog4fxxnC65ARIS6m24RXc92OvnVwk0I00cO4knx8/X9/328nH/5Xl75/m8XK@X1@NQDUetjlKlslMTQIeqjebm9ubCo4bSdGyQRLo9QrpZPoPOoJUFZ7jPnshqSBVlkEvEWAOE7VmwiHzXltBnxTmuM6Q/eznBZNcyjsaYBKg7e5whkebdETzOniB1BqfNtO2yEUvI4TVXcuEUH5iY51r4QykgUOBCXgd1k2dvb4Yavm93sXKtd0VfYP7D1QM)

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>43</s> 40 bytes

Returns `0` / `true`.

```js
f=([k,...a],n=0)=>!k||k-n&&7-k-n&&f(a,k)
```

#### Test cases

```js
f=([k,...a],n=0)=>!k||k-n&&7-k-n&&f(a,k)

console.log('Testing truthy cases ...');
console.log(f('1353531414'));
console.log(f('3132124215'));
console.log(f('4142124136'));
console.log(f('46'));
console.log(f('4264626313135414154'));
console.log(f('6'));
console.log(f('2642156451212623232354621262412315654626212421451351563264123656353126413154124151545145146535351323'));
console.log(f('5414142'));

console.log('Testing falsy cases ...');
console.log(f('11'));
console.log(f('3132124225'));
console.log(f('6423126354214136312144245354241324231415135454535141512135141323542451231236354513265426114231536245'));
console.log(f('553141454631'));
console.log(f('14265411'));
console.log(f('16'));
console.log(f('42123523545426464236231321'));
console.log(f('61362462636351'));
console.log(f('62362462636361'));
```

Comment: Sadly the simple port of the Retina answer is only 38 bytes.

Comment: @Neil I think it's actually 37 with `test()`

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally pasted a newline into the byte counter.

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 22 bytes

Using a regex:

```
{!/(.)<{"$0|"~7-$0}>/}
```

Takes the input as a string. Inspired by [G B's Ruby answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/104048/14880).
How it works:

- `/  /`: A regex.
- `(.)`: Match any character, and capture it as `$0`.
- `<{  }>`: Dynamically generate a sub-regex to be matched at that position.
- `"$0|" ~ (7 - $0)`: The sub-regex we generate is one that matches only the previous digit, or 7 minus the previous digit (e.g. `5|2`).
  Thus the overall regex will match iff it finds an invalid consecutive pair of digits anywhere.
- `{!  }`: Coerce to a boolean (causing the regex to be matched against `$_`), negate it, and turn the whole thing into a lambda (with implicit parameter `$_`).

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 38 bytes

Using list processing:

```
{all ([!=] 7-.[1],|$_ for .[1..*]Z$_)}
```

Takes the input as an array of integers.
How it works:

- `.[1..*] Z $_`: Zip the input list with an offset-by-one version of itself, to generate a list of 2-tuples of consecutive digits.
- `[!=] 7 - .[1], |$_`: For each of those, check if `(7 - b) != a != b`.
- `all (  )`: Return a truthy or falsy value depending on whether all loop iterations returned True.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript <s>61</s> 43 bytes

Comments have mentioned I can't use C# linq functions without including the using statement, so here's the exact same in less bytes using standard JS...

```js
f=a=>a.reduce((i,j)=>i>6|i==j|i+j==7?9:j)<7
```

## C#, <s>99</s> <s>67</s> 65 bytes

Takes input as an int array `a`

```c#
// new solution using linq
bool A(int[]a){return a.Aggregate((i,j)=>i>6|i==j|i+j==7?9:j)<7;}
```

```c#
// old solution using for loop
bool A(int[]a){for(int i=1;i<a.Length;)if(a[i]==a[i-1]|a[i-1]+a[i++]==7)return false;return true;}
```

Explanation:

```c#
// method that returns a boolean taking an integer array as a parameter
bool A(int[] a) 
{
    // aggregate loops over a collection, 
    // returning the output of the lambda 
    // as the first argument of the next iteration
    return a.Aggregate((i, j) => i > 6 // if the first arg (i) > than 6
    | i == j      // or i and j match
    | i + j == 7  // or i + j = 7
    ? 9   // return 9 as the output (and therefore the next i value)
    : j   // otherwise return j as the output (and therefore the next i value)
    ) 
    // if the output is ever set to 9 then it will be carried through to the end
    < 7; // return the output is less than 7 (not 9)
}
```

Comment: I think this needs to be wrapped in a function, or maybe a lambda (does C# have those?) Also, you could save a few bytes by returning `0` or `1` instead of `false` or `true`

Comment: oh, ok - first post on code golf. I'll edit...

Comment: No problem. BTW, welcome to the site! :)

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Correct me if I'm wrong but since the output requirement is truthy/falsey then the output options are language dependent tl;dr 1/0 are not truthy/falsey in c#

Comment: @Phaeze You're correct that they're not truthy/falsey, but the standard IO rules http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods reckon you can output using exit codes and that functions can output in the same way as programs. I'll change back to booleans if required, but it'll cost me a few bites

Comment: Fair enough, i just wan't sure how that rule applied to c# since it's kind of the black sheep for that :), either way though very nice answer

Comment: @Phaeze Cheers - I'm working on a lambda solution now, but if it comes to nought i'll switch to booleans. If i'm gonna play, i might as well play by the rules :)

Comment: Nice good luck. I'm working on a linq solution, trying really hard to get sub 90 ;)

Comment: When using linq functions your submission has to also include the using statement

Comment: You can save two bytes by replacing "==9" and "!=9" with ">6" and "<9", which serve the same purpose:
    bool A(int[]a){return a.Aggregate((i,j)=>i>6|i==j|i+j==7?9:j)<9;}

Comment: @BenceJoful thanks! edited

Comment: @Phaeze really? that sucks. where's that written?

Comment: I'll try to find a post on it, I picked it up just from reading through challenges over the years. but to give an example as to why, in c# 6 you can import a static so you could assume that import and only call `Sqrt()` instead of `Math.Sqrt()`

Comment: Here is a general answer http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/383/should-imports-includes-count-in-golf   it mentions that the std import can be exlcuded which holds true for c# the compiler will automatically add that one.

Comment: And heres a better one that links to the different scenarios that have been asked. http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/10848/19547

Comment: @Phaeze fair enough. I've switch the implementation to javascript's reduce function, and saved a few bites.

Answer (score 4):

### Python, 38 bytes

```python
f=lambda h,*t:t==()or 7>h^t[0]>0<f(*t)
```

A recursive function that takes arguments like `f(1,2,3)`.

This makes use of argument unpacking to extract the first number into `h` and the rest into the tuple `t`. If `t` is empty, output True. Otherwise, use [Zgarb's bit trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/104074/20260) to check that the first two die rolls are not incompatible. Then, check that the result also holds on the recursive call on the tail.

Answer (score 3):

## Processing, <s>93</s> <s>92</s> 90 bytes

*Changed* `||` *to* `|` *: 1 byte saved thanks to @ClaytonRamsey*

*Started counting backwards: 2 bytes saved thanks to @IsmaelMiguel*

```java
int b(int[]s){for(int i=s.length;--i>0;)if(s[i-1]==s[i]|s[i-1]==7-s[i])return 0;return 1;}
```

Takes input as an array of ints, output `1` for true or `0` for false.

#### Ungolfed

```java
int Q104044(int[]s){
  for(int i=s.length;--i>0;)
    if(s[i-1]==s[i]|s[i-1]==7-s[i])
      return 0;
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: Usually Java allows | instead of || if you want to save a byte.

Comment: @ClaytonRamsey I don't know why I didn't think of it, thanks!

Comment: I found another one. You could cut down on the use of returns with the tertiary operator

Comment: @ClaytonRamsey The `return 0` is inside the if-statement while `return 1` is not. I don't see how that is possible unless you have some other idea

Comment: never mind, I misread your code

Comment: But I'm glad that someone is trying to help me golf this verbosity :)

Comment: Why don't you loop the array backwards? That should save 1-2 bytes. Something like `for(int i=s.length-1;--i;)`. I'm not sure if this works.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Thank you, this saves me 2 bytes!

Comment: Wow, I really wasn't expecting it to work! I know barely anything about Java and Processing.

Comment: `Golfed it! Yipee! (nobody's going to read these summaries so why not have fun :)` <-- I read it, while comparing what you have with what you had.

Answer (score 3):

## ><> (Fish) 47 bytes

```
0:i:1+?!v\!
   0n;n1< >
!?-{:-"0"/^
!? -{-$7:/^
```

Pretty simple;

Line 1: check to see if inputted a number, if no number (EOF) then we have a truthy to print else checks.

Line 2: print outcome.

Line 3: turn input into number (ASCII 0 - from input), then check if it's equal to previous input.

Line 4: check if input is opposite side of die.

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), <s>57</s> <s>44</s> 41 bytes

<sub>*([Crossed out 44 is still regular 44](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7427/42963))*</sub>

```
0-notin($args|%{7-$_-$l-and$l-ne($l=$_)})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#@2@gm5dfkpmnoZJYlF5co1ptrqsSr6uSo5uYlwIk81I1VHJsVeI1azX///9v9t/wv/F/MwA)

*(OP has clarified that taking input as separate arguments is OK - saved 13 bytes ... saved another 3 bytes by eliminating `$b`)*

We're looping through the input `$args` a digit at a time. Each digit, we verify that the `$l`ast digit is `-n`ot`e`qual to the current digit `$_`, and that `7-$_-$l` is some number other than zero (which is truthy). Those Boolean results are encapsulated in parens and fed into the right-hand operand of the `-notin` operator, checking against `0`. In other words, if there is any `False` value anywhere in the loop, the `-notin` will also be `False`. That Boolean is left on the pipeline, and output is implicit.

Lengthy because of the `$` requirement for variable names, and that Boolean commands `-ne` `-and` are verbose in PowerShell. Oh well.

Answer (score 3):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak) 128 Bytes

```
(()){{}(({}<>)<>[({})])}{}([]){{{}}<>}{}([]){{}({}({})<>)<>([][()])}{}(<{}>)<>(([])){{}{}({}[(()()()){}()]){<>}<>([][()])}({}{})
```

Outputs 0 for falsey, or -7 for truthy.

[Try it Online!](http://brain-flak.tryitonline.net/#code=KCgpKXt7fSgoe308Pik8Plsoe30pXSl9e30oW10pe3t7fX08Pn17fShbXSl7e30oe30oe30pPD4pPD4oW11bKCldKX17fSg8e30-KTw-KChbXSkpe3t9e30oe31bKCgpKCkoKSl7fSgpXSl7PD59PD4oW11bKCldKX0oe317fSk&input=MiA2IDQgMiAxIDUgNiA0IDUgMSAyIDEgMiA2IDIgMyAyIDMgMiAzIDUgNCA2IDIgMSAyIDYgMiA0IDEgMiAzIDEgNSA2IDUgNCA2IDIgNiAyIDEgMiA0IDIgMSA0IDUgMSAzIDUgMSA1IDYgMyAyIDYgNCAxIDIgMyA2IDUgNiAzIDUgMyAxIDIgNiA0IDEgMyAxIDUgNCAxIDIgNCAxIDUgMSA1IDQgNSAxIDQgNSAxIDQgNiA1IDMgNSAzIDUgMSAzIDIgMw) (Truthy)
[Try it Online!](http://brain-flak.tryitonline.net/#code=KCgpKXt7fSgoe308Pik8Plsoe30pXSl9e30oW10pe3t7fX08Pn17fShbXSl7e30oe30oe30pPD4pPD4oW11bKCldKX17fSg8e30-KTw-KChbXSkpe3t9e30oe31bKCgpKCkoKSl7fSgpXSl7PD59PD4oW11bKCldKX0oe317fSk&input=NiA0IDIgMyAxIDIgNiAzIDUgNCAyIDEgNCAxIDMgNiAzIDEgMiAxIDQgNCAyIDQgNSAzIDUgNCAyIDQgMSAzIDIgNCAyIDMgMSA0IDEgNSAxIDMgNSA0IDUgNCA1IDMgNSAxIDQgMSA1IDEgMiAxIDMgNSAxIDQgMSAzIDIgMyA1IDQgMiA0IDUgMSAyIDMgMSAyIDMgNiAzIDUgNCA1IDEgMyAyIDYgNSA0IDIgNiAxIDEgNCAyIDMgMSA1IDMgNiAyIDQgNQ) (Flasey)

**Explanation (t stands for top and s stands for second from the top):**

```
(())                # push a 1 to get this loop started
{{}                 # loop through all pairs, or until 2 are equal
(({}<>)<>[({})])    # pop t, push t on the other stack, and t - s on this one
}{}                 # end loop and pop one more time
([])                # push the height of the stack
{                   # if the height isn't 0 (there were equal numbers)...
{{}}<>              # pop everything from this stack and switch
}                   # end if
{{}                 # for every pair on the stack: pop the height and...
({}({})<>)<>        # push t + s on the other stack leaving s on this one
([][()])            # push the height - 1
}                   # end loop when there is only 1 number left
{}(<{}>)<>          # pop t, pop s, push 0 and switch stacks
(([]))              # push the height twice
{                   # loop through every pair
{}{}                # pop the height and what was t - 7
({}[(()()()){}()])  # push t - 7
{<>}<>              # if t is not 0 switch stacks and come come back
                    # if t is 0 (ie, there was a pair that added to 7) just switch once
([][()])            # push height - 1
}                   # end loop
({}{})              # push t + s (either 0 + 0 or 0 + -7)
```

Answer (score 3):

## MATLAB, 30 bytes

```
@(a)all(diff(a)&movsum(a,2)-7)
```

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 63 bytes

```php
for($d=$argv[$i=1];$c=$argv[++$i];$d=$c)$d-$c&&$d+$c-7?:die(1);
```

takes input as list of command arguments; exits with `1` (error) if input is invalid, `0` (ok) if valid.

Run with `-nr`.

**input as string argument, 65 bytes**

```php
for($d=($s=$argv[1])[0];$c=$s[++$i];$d=$c)$d-$c&&$d+$c-7?:die(1);
```

Answer (score 3):

**C <del>47</del> 44 bytes**

```
F(char*s){return!s[1]||(*s^s[1])%7&&F(s+1);}
```

takes a string of digits (or a zero terminated array of bytes)

Explanation

`F(char*s){`

according to the standard `int` return type is implied. (saving 4 bytes)

`return` unconditional return because this is a recursive function

using shortcut evaluation:

`!s[1]||` if the second character is *nul* return true

`((*s^s[1])%7&&` if the first two charcters aren't legal false

`F(s+1))` check the rest of the string in the same way

that confusing expression

`*s` is the first character `s[1]` is the second

`*s^s[1]` exclusive-ors them together if they are the same the result is 0 
  if they add to 7 the result is 7 , (if they differ and don't add to 7 the result is between 1 and 6 inclusive)

so `(*s^s[1])%7` is zero for bad input and non-zero otherwise, thus false if these 2 characters are bad, and true otherwise

**comment:**  as this function call uses only end-recursion (only the last statement is a recursive call) an optimiser could translate the recursion into a loop, this is a happy conicidence and is obviously not worth any golf score, but in the real word makes it possible to process strings of any length without running out of stack.

Comment: About your `!((*s^s[1])%7)` I think you don't want the `!`.  Zero values for bad input would be falsy, so you want to return the falsy when it's bad.

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 71 bytes

```
f=lambda s:len(s)<2or(s[0]!=s[1]and int(s[0])!=7-int(s[1]))and f(s[1:])
```

Uses a recursive approach.

Explanation:

```
f=lambda s:                                                              # Define a function which takes an argument, s
           len(s)<2 or                                                   # Return True if s is just one character
                      (s[0]!=s[1]                                        # If the first two characters matches or...
                                 and int(s[0])!=7-int(s[1])              # the first character is 7 - the next character, then return False
                                                           )and f(s[1:]) # Else, recurse with s without the first character
```

Comment: say that the input is a list of ints, and then you don't need the casts.

Answer (score 2):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 28 bytes

```
M`(.)\1|16|25|34|43|52|61
^0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#RZDLTYRBDIPv6QNpuSCcVwuc6ACttpDpffn8rwSaOcSxkzh5u309nt@P28f7j4725Jzq03Umzyrun8@nanhqdZQqlZ2aADpUbTQ/tzcXHjWUpmODJNLtEdLN8ht0Bq0sOMN99URWQ6oog1wixhogbM@CReS/toQ@K65xnSH92csJJruWcTTGJEDd2eMMiTTvjuBx9gKpK7hspm2XjVhCDq@5kgunWGBiXmdhh1JAoMCFfA7qJq/evgw1rG93sXKtb0VfYP7D1S8)

Alternatively:

```
M`[16]{2}|[25]{2}|[34]{2}
^0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#RZDLbQNBDEPv6iNAjqZ@LeSUCowE7sNJ7evHXSDBDDCiSEkcvb1/PI7Px1379czfn3vO9Vb7je/bcaiGo1ZHqVLZqQmgQ9VGc3N7c@FRQ2k6Nkgi3R4h3SyfQWfQyoIz3KsnshpSRRnkEjHWAGF7Fiwi37Ul9FlxjusM6c9eTjDZtYyjMSYB6s4eZ0ikeXcEj7MnSJ3BaTNtu2zEEnJ4zZVcOMUHJuZaC38oBQQKXMjroG7y7O3NUMP37S5WrvWu6AvMf7h6AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 9 bytes

```
dG2YCs7-h
```

The input is an array of numbers representing the digits.

The output is a non-empty array, which is truthy if all its entries are non-zero, and falsy otherwise (read more about MATL's criterion for truthy and falsy [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/95057/36398)).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@5/ibhTpXGyum/H/f7ShgrGCKRQbKpiAcCwA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#bVI9T0MxDNz5FdnexBA7DiMDbF0ZQFUlkBDqwETL0KG//ZH4zuYNHfJl587nS95fd@vnTt6eTg/3x/VxOf/8no@X5bp8fXyfLsvh@WXd16LFOGppcxzu9nOvRcYsIzZXG1HPZnTe6B7FLKWPaPcV@DFshMhrzjzv4qaz@s6csTpSvC6GkS8yzXdKnGW1rU6wqc/mSlANyM4Yuo0MGFv2ZTxb8jVHhlPwRkcnQNGXca6l3nBP3D30HHXRnRCt9Azn5jjLO418gQ@NSpUtdUVG0oPA/nNZuiisa@ma0Ne5Vr423FG@gHnXm9/Cd1DvvBILXxCJ31GpQja64880apGS3rljNevGv4JeZOVmts/sHw).

#### Explanation

```
d     % Take input implicitly. Consecutive differences
G     % Push input again
2YC   % Overlapping blocks of length 2, arranged as columns of a matrix
s     % Sum of each column
7-    % Subtract 7, element-wise
h     % Concatenate horizontally. Implicitly display
```

Comment: Is it possible/intended to add some new  MATLAB functions to MATL?

Comment: @rahnema1 Yes, there are some function names currently unused. However, I tend to be selective and add only those that I think will be used often. If you have any proposals we can discuss them in the [MATL chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39466/matl-chatl) :-)

Comment: @rahnema1 If you are thinking of `movsum`, there's already `conv2` (which includes `conv`); see `Y+` and `Z+`

Answer (score 2):

## C# (with Linq) <s>90</s> <s>81</s> <s>73</s> <s>71</s> <s>69</s> 68 Bytes

```
using System.Linq;n=>n.Aggregate((p,c)=>p<9|c==p|c==103-p?'\b':c)>9;
```

### Explanation:

```
using System.Linq;           //Obligatory import
n=>n.Aggregate((p,c)=>       //p serves as both previous character in chain and error flag
    p<9                      //8 is the error flag, if true input is already invalid            
        |c==p            
            |c==103-p        //103 comes from 55(7) + 48(0)
                ?'\b'       //'\b' because it has a single digit code (8)
                    :c)      //valid so set previous character, this catches the first digit case as well
                        >8;  //as long as the output char is not a backspace input is valid
```

Answer (score 2):

**C, 81 bytes, was 85 bytes**

```
int F(int *A,int L){int s=1;while(--L)s&=A[L]!=A[L-1]&A[L]!=(7-A[L-1]);return s;}
```

Input is an array of integers A with length L.
Returns 1 for true and 0 for false. The input is checked from the end to the start using the input length L as the array index.

Comment: `int ` is optional at the start, you can save 4 bytes.

Comment: `int s=1;` can be declared outside the function as `s=1;` for another 4.

Comment: [68 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/7/Y2k3DUcdHMzOvRMvRujotv0ij2NbQWlfXx1qzWM3WMdonVhdI6BrGqqmBOebaEK51UWpJaVGeQrF17f/cxMw8Dc1qroIioDFpGkqqKTF5SjpuGj5KMSYxZko6Rpqa1tgkDWMMoZK1/wE "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 37 bytes

```
f(a:b:c)=a+b/=7&&a/=b&&f(b:c)
f _=1<2
```

Usage example: `f [1,5,2]` -> `False`.

Simple recursion. Base case: single element list, which returns `True`. Recursive case: let `a` and `b` be the first two elements of the input list and `c` the rest. All of the following conditions must hold: `a+b/=7`, `a/=b` and the recursive call with `a` dropped.

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript, 40 bytes

```
f=i=>i.reduce((a,b)=>a&&a-b&&a+b-7&&b,9)
```

Takes advantage of the JavaScript feature that `&&` will return the last value that is parsed (either the falsy term or the last term). `0` is passed along if it doesn't meet the conditions, and the previous term is passed along otherwise. The 9 makes sure that it starts with a truthy value.

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy, 61 bytes

```
{i=0;!(true in it.tail().collect{x->x in [7-it[i],it[i++]]})}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 58 Bytes

```
lambda x:all(x[i]!=x[i+1]!=7-x[i]for i in range(len(x)-1))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 39 bytes

```
0>i'0'-::&0)?v1n;>&!
?=0+=7+@=}:{:<;n0^
```

[Try it online!](http://fish.tryitonline.net/#code=MD5pJzAnLTo6JjApP3Yxbjs-JiEKPz0wKz03K0A9fTp7Ojw7bjBe&input=MjY0MjE1NjQ1MTIxMjYyMzIzMjM1NDYyMTI2MjQxMjMxNTY1NDYyNjIxMjQyMTQ1MTM1MTU2MzI2NDEyMzY1NjM1MzEyNjQxMzE1NDEyNDE1MTU0NTE0NTE0NjUzNTM1MTMyMw)

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 102 bytes

```
@set s=%1
@set/an=0%s:~0,2%,r=n%%9*(n%%7)
@if %r%==0 exit/b
@if %n% gtr 6 %0 %s:~1%
@echo 1
```

Ungolfed:

```
@echo off
rem grab the input string
set s=%1
:loop
rem convert the first two digits as octal
set /a n = 0%s:~0,2%
rem check for divisibility by 9 (011...066)
set /a r = n %% 9
rem exit with no (falsy) output if no remainder
if %r% == 0 exit/b
rem check for divisibility by 7 (016...061)
set /a r = n %% 7
rem exit with no (falsy) output if no remainder
if %r% == 0 exit/b
rem remove first digit
set s=%s:~1%
rem loop back if there were at least two digits
if %n% gtr 6 goto loop
rem truthy output
echo 1
```

Answer (score 1):

**Clojure, <s>55</s> <s>49</s> 46 bytes**

*edit 1*: using `(mapcat ...)` instead of `(flatten(map ...))`

*edit 2*: using `(juxt - +)` instead of `(juxt = +)`, checking for values `0` or `7`

```
#(not(some #{0 7}(mapcat(juxt - +)(rest %)%)))
```

Consecutive values are not allowed to be equal (difference = `0`) or sum up to `7`. Got to use `juxt` again :)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 46 Bytes

```
a=>r=1&&a.reduce((c,p)=>r=c==p||c==7-p?0:1)&&r
```

```js
f=a=>r=1&&a.reduce((c,p)=>r=c==p||c==7-p?0:1)&&r;

console.log(f([4,6]));
console.log(f([1,6]));
```

Answer (score 1):

## Bash, 60 bytes

```
f(){ 
while [ $2 ]
do
(( ($1^$2)%7 ))||return 1
shift
done
}
```

Takes separate arguments as input.

### Explanation

`while`-`do`-`shift`-`done` loops though the arguments giving each pair a turn as (`$1`,`$2`) if the loop completes truth is returned.

The complicated expression  `(( ($1^$2)%7 ))`
exclusive-ors the the arguments being tested together and `mod(7)`s them.

Valid pairs will result in non-zero, invalid ones in zero.

`((`...`))` yields true when the arithmetic returns non-zero.

`||` runs the next command if the previous was false  (in this context that means if the arithmetic above returned 0).

Unix shell treats zero as true (except as above) so `return 1` yields a false result from this function when an invalid pair is found.

Answer (score 1):

## Prolog (SWI), 45 bytes

```
p([A,B|T]):-A+B=\=7,A\=B,p([B|T]).
p([_|[]]).
```

[Online interpreter](http://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/OQQxZGvy.pl)

Answer (score 1):

## Math++, 111 bytes

```
?>b
0>n
n+1>n
b%10>{n}
_(b/1)>b
3+4*!b>$
0>n
n+1>n
10+4*!({n}-{n+1})>$
11+3*!(7-{n}-{n+1})>$
8+4*!{n}>$
1
0>$
0
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 32 bytes

```
FreeQ[Most@#~BitXor~Rest@#,0|7]&
```

Unnamed function taking a list of integers as input and outputting `True` or `False`. Like many existing answers, it computes the bitwise XOR of consecutive elements of the input, and checks that the answer is never 0 nor 7.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 41 bytes

```
<?=!similar_text(aa^af,$s^s.$s=$argv[1]);
```

Takes input as a string. Prints `1` if the input is valid, an empty string otherwise.

Calculates XOR by pairs of adjacent characters, using shifted version of the input. Then searches for `0x00` or `0x07` characters in it.

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, 65 bytes

```
DEF T A
WHILE LEN(A)V=POP(A)IF!(O-V&&7-O-V)THEN?0A
O=V
WEND?1
END
```

This can definitely be made a little smaller